# How to add literal attribute to a Flask-SQLAlchemy model and schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have a SQLAlchemy ORM model and schema based on **Flask-SQLAlchemy** such as :

```
class Demo(Base):
  status_map = {
    0: "Ok",
    1: "Failed"
  }

  name = db.Column(db.String(10))
  status = db.Column(db.Integer)


class DemoSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        load_instance = True
        ordered = True
```

I want to add a **class column** which returns for each object instance the dictionary **'status_map'** containing the matching between the status value and its meaning as a string, in order to know the meaning of the status value.

This column does not exist in the database. It should always contain **'DEMO.status_map'** content.

I've tried different solutions but no one is working.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I managed to get through with:

```
class Demo(Base):
  status_map = {
    "Ok", 0
    "Failed": 1
  }

  name = db.Column(db.String(10))
  status = db.Column(db.Integer)

class DemoSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    status_name = fields.Method("get_status_name")

    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        load_instance = True
     
    def get_status_name(self, obj):
        return Demo.status_map
```

The status_map must have string keys for serialization.

It works perfectly without any overhead from the query done on Demo class.